# Saving only a portion of each member of a Python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python:

```
list = ['hello there 123 456', 'hello there 234 567', 'hello there 345 678']
```

I want to change it to:

```
list = ['123','234','345']
```

How can I save only the first integer occurrence of each index?

The first integer will always be preceded by the same number of character entries/words.

Comment: This sample list has invalid syntax.  Could you please fix it?

Comment: What exactly are the list items? Tuples? If so, what are the elements of the tuples? There are no commas in the parentheses and no quotation marks.

Comment: Also, in your desired output, `(123)` is not a single-element tuple, it's the exact same thing as `123`. If you want a (non-empty) tuple, you need commas, as in `(123,)`.

Comment: I updated the original post with fixed syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that your sample list is valid, I can help you.

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> # Please don't name a variable `list` -- it overshadows the built-in.
>>> lst = ['hello there 123 456', 'hello there 234 567', 'hello there 345 678']
>>> [x.split()[2] for x in lst]
['123', '234', '345']
>>>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. Now I see how to split individual entries of a list. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

if your list is like this:

```
list1 = [("hello", 'there', 123, 456, 789), ('hello', 'there', 234, 567, 890), ('hello', 'there', 345, 678, 912)]
```

then simply use list comprehension like so:

```
new_lst = [i[2] for i in list1]
```

`new_lst` will now be `[123, 234, 345]`

---

### EDIT

with the new syntax do something like this:

```
list = ['hello there 123 456', 'hello there 234 567', 'hello there 345 678']
new_lst = [i.split(' ')[2] for i in list1]
```

`new_lst` will now give the same result

Comment: Sorry, the syntax of my list was incorrect and unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible implementation of `get_portion` function

```
>>> def get_portion(s):
...     return next(i for i in s.split() if i.isdigit())
... 
>>> L = ['hello there 123 456', 'hello there 234 567', 'hello there 345 678']
>>> [get_portion(s) for s in L]
['123', '234', '345']
```

By using an explicit function, you can easily write [doctests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)/[unittests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). Here is an example with doctests

```
def get_portion(n):
    """Return the first chunk of digits in a string.

    >>> get_portion('hello there 123 456')
    '123'
    >>> get_portion('hello there 234 567')
    '234'
    >>> get_portion('hello there 345 678')
    '345'
    """
    return next(i for i in s.split() if i.isdigit())
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't know that the integer is at index 2, but you know that "The first integer will always be preceded by the same number of character entries/words.", then precede it with a test on the first element to find that index:

```
ofst = None
for x, elem in enumerate(list1[0].split()):
    try:
        int(elem)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    ofst = x
    break
else:
    print "No integer found."
    return

new_lst = [i.split()[ofst] for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have a list of strings:

```
['hello there 123 456', 'hello there 234 567', 'hello there 345 678']
```

And you want to get the "first integer", when the prefix will always be the same length and have the same number of spaces.

There are at least three ways you can do that:

- Split into words, and get the first one that's a valid integer.
- Split into words, and get the third word.
- Slice out the three characters you want.

Which one is best? It depends on what rule best fits the definition in your head when you created this format—or the definition in someone else's head when they created it, or the definition in your head when you figured it out, or… whatever. They're all so easy to do that the only deciding choice is which one reads naturally for this particular use case.

And then, whichever one you choose, you need to do that to each string in the list. A list comprehension is perfect for that.

So:

```
new_list = [next(word for word in value if word.isdigit()) for value in original_list]
new_list = [value.split()[2] for value in original_list]
new_list = [value[12:15] for value in original_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in a given column:

```
START_CH = 12
list = [s[START_CH:].split(1)[0] for s in list]
```

Starting on a given word:

```
WORD = 3
list = [s.split(WORD)[WORD-1] for s in list]
```